# Firebase remote config : condition limitations

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-remote-config

we have installed Firebase remote config in our android and iOS applications and have added the different build variants into conditions (testing vs prod).
The problem is that any person in the project can change these conditions.

Is there a way to allow only a few people to be able to modify these conditions while keeping the "test" conditions manageable by all members of the project?

Answer (score 0):

In a Firebase project, you can grant users read/write access to specific products. But there's no way to assign them different permissions *within* a specific product.

You'll want to separate your "testing" and "prod" environments into separate projects in that case. That is the recommended practice for [multi-environment setups](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects#support_different_environments), as it also keeps other data (analytics, authentication, etc) for each environment separated.